# Open sidebar menu in angular with *ngIf and *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I know it's supposed to be simple but I'm trying to find a nice way to do the following:

I have a menu in my sidebar and I want that by clicking on a specific span it will not rout me somewhere but will show me another menu within it.
Below is the code:

**sidebar.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span>{{item.label}}
<div *ngIf="isClicked" *ngFor="let nestedItem of item.nestedItems" class="nav-nestedItem-label">
  {{nestedItem.label}}
</div>
```

**sidebar.ts**

```
      this.items = [
    { label: 'A', image: 'dashboard', route: 'AAA' },
    { label: 'B', image: 'my-apps', route: 'BBB' },
    { label: 'C', image: 'app-store', route: 'CCC' },
    { label: 'D', image: 'data', route: 'DDD' },
    { label: 'E', image: 'commercial-tools', route: 'EEE' },
    { label: 'F', image: 'dev-tools', route: 'FFF', },
    { label: 'G', image: 'data-source-mng', route: '',
        nestedItems: [{label: 'GA'},
                      {label: 'GB'},
                      {label: 'GC'}]},
    
  ];
```

I want the nestedItems to open for me by pressing lable 'G' and it will nor rout to anywhere.

He is currently showing me the entire menu including the nestedItems

How can this be arranged in a beautiful and non-primitive way? I did some way but the code is long and cumbersome. I need a beautiful way

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
items = [
    { label: 'A', image: 'dashboard', route: 'AAA' },
    { label: 'B', image: 'my-apps', route: 'BBB' },
    { label: 'C', image: 'app-store', route: 'CCC' },
    { label: 'D', image: 'data', route: 'DDD' },
    { label: 'E', image: 'commercial-tools', route: 'EEE' },
    { label: 'F', image: 'dev-tools', route: 'FFF', },
    { label: 'G', image: 'data-source-mng', route: '',
        nestedItems: [{label: 'GA', route: 'GAAA'},
                      {label: 'GB', route: 'GBBB'},
                      {label: 'GC', route: 'GCCC'}]},
    
  ];

  myClick(item: any, event?: any): void {
    if (item.nestedItems) {
      event.target.querySelector('div').hidden = false;
    } else {
      // redirect to...
    }
  }
```

and your html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="myClick(item, $event)">
    <span>{{item.label}}
        <div hidden="true" *ngIf="item.nestedItems" class="nav-nestedItem-label">
            <div *ngFor="let nestedItem of item.nestedItems" (click)="myClick(nestedItem)">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;>&nbsp;{{nestedItem.label}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:
I've add 1 more nested item;

```
items = [
    { label: 'A', image: 'dashboard', route: 'AAA' },
    { label: 'B', image: 'my-apps', route: 'BBB' },
    { label: 'C', image: 'app-store', route: 'CCC' },
    { label: 'D', image: 'data', route: 'DDD' },
    { label: 'E', image: 'commercial-tools', route: 'EEE' },
    { label: 'F', image: 'dev-tools', route: '',
      nestedItems: [
        {label: 'FA', route: 'FAAA'},
        {label: 'FB', route: 'FBBB'},
        {label: 'FC', route: '',
          nestedItems: [
            {label: 'FCA', route: 'FCAAA'},
            {label: 'FCB', route: 'FCBBB'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { label: 'G', image: 'data-source-mng', route: '',
        nestedItems: [
          {label: 'GA', route: 'GAAA'},
          {label: 'GB', route: 'GBBB'},
          {label: 'GC', route: 'GCCC'}
        ]
    },
    
  ];
```

and see the next code to manage it:

```
myClick(item: any, event?: any): void {
    if (item.nestedItems) {
      event.target.querySelector('ul').hidden = !event.target.querySelector('ul').hidden;
      event.stopPropagation();
      // hide false
    } else {
      // redirect to...
    }
  }
```

template:

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveItem; context:{ list: items }">
    </ng-container>
</ul>

<ng-template #recursiveItem let-list="list">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
        <li (click)="myClick(item, $event)">
            {{item.label}}
            <ng-container *ngIf="item.nestedItems">
                <ul hidden="true">
                    <ng-container
                        [ngTemplateOutlet]="recursiveItem"
                        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{list:item.nestedItems}">
                    </ng-container>
                </ul>
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much the solution is really good!
The thing is that even within the menu that opens for me, another menu should open.
In the html code it looks really ugly and not pretty when there is so much div with ngFor and ngIf
Is there a way to do this through the TS without all this awkwardness?

Comment: you can create a component for the span that calls itself recursively

Comment: I know I can. But I want to do it without creating another component

Comment: Edited. Let me know if you like the last tip.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the clicked menu item in a property. You can then use `*ngIf` to compare the loop `item` with the clicked item to decide whether or not to show the menu item.

**component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="expand(item)">
  <span>{{item.label}}</span>
  <ng-container *ngIf="item === expanded">
    <div *ngFor="let nestedItem of item.nestedItems">
      {{nestedItem.label}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

`(click)="expand(item)"` handles click events on the outer div, passing in the current `item` as the single argument.

`<ng-container>` is an angular component that doesn't get rendered (also, you can't use both `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same element)

`*ngIf="item === expanded"` only renders the `<ng-container>` when the `expanded` item is the same object as the current `item`.

**component.ts**

```js
  items: Item[] = [
    { label: 'A', image: 'dashboard', route: 'AAA' },
    { label: 'B', image: 'my-apps', route: 'BBB' },
    { label: 'C', image: 'app-store', route: 'CCC' },
    { label: 'D', image: 'data', route: 'DDD' },
    { label: 'E', image: 'commercial-tools', route: 'EEE' },
    {
      label: 'F',
      image: 'dev-tools',
      nestedItems: [{ label: 'FA', route: 'FAAA' }],
    },
    {
      label: 'G',
      image: 'data-source-mng',
      nestedItems: [
        { label: 'GA', route: 'GAAA' },
        { label: 'GB', route: 'GBBB' },
        { label: 'GC', route: 'GCCC' },
      ],
    },
  ];

  expanded?: Item;

  expand(item: Item): void {
    this.expanded = item;
  }
```

I have created 2 interfaces as below. You could also declare `expanded: any;` without using interfaces, but my personal preference is to use types where possible.

```js
interface Item {
  label: string;
  image?: string;
  route?: string;
  nestedItems?: SubItem[];
}

interface SubItem {
  label: string;
  route: string;
}
```

Outside of scope: collapsing the menu item when elements outside of the menu are clicked.

Stackblitz Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f1kifq?file=src/app/app.component.html